# Removing event listeners

Tags: javascript

If I add an event handler to an event like

```
HTMLElement.onclick = somefunction;
```

How can I remove the event handler added in the above style.

I tried using removeEventListener like below, but it didn't work.

```
HTMLElement.removeEventListener('click', somefunction)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Easy, you use `addEventListener` instead, and stop using inline event handlers.

Comment: Or you could resort to horrible hacks, like `HTMLElement.onclick = function() {};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the `onclick` assignment method, you need to re-assign `onclick` to a different value to "unbind" it, e.g.:

```
HTMLElement.onclick = null;
```

Please note though that using `onclick` is considered bad practice as it doesn't allow you to bind multiple functions, prefer [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: Calling legitimate and reliable techniques a "bad practice" is a bad practice. ;)

Comment: Well that's why I said "considered" bad practice, implying that this is the common wisdom, not *"It IS bad practice that's a fact!"*, and gave the main reason as to why.

Comment: Relax dood, it was mostly tongue in cheek. Already gave you +1. Still, while it may be common, I wouldn't call it wisdom. You get guys like the user  "adeneo" above who use terms like "horrible hacks" yet clearly don't really even know how to do what's needed.

Comment: No personal feelings lol, just defending my point. For what's clearly a newbie question I think it's helpful to discourage using it, because the few cases where an advanced user would use `onevent` properties instead of `addEventListener` are, well, few and not interesting for a beginner. On the other hand, organizing JS code is a struggle that's better tackled early :)

Comment: Agreed. JS is a mess. The *EventListener* interface that you can use with `.addEventListener()` is IMO one of the biggest features for organizing code into a sane application structure.

Answer (score 2):

Use `addEventListener` with `removeEventListener`

Example

```
HTMLElement.addEventListener('click', somefunction)
HTMLElement.removeEventListener('click', somefunction)
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. *"How can I remove the event handler added in the above style."*